# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject' not found

Tags: json.net

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL project, and in it we are using JSON.NET to Serialize and deserialize. This works for 3 of our developers. On our 4th developers computer, anything that uses the deserialize function works fine, however if a line runs that uses Serialize, he gets the error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject' not found.
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how:
1) One method cant be found from a library, even though another one is working fine from the same library
2) How this is happening only on one developers machine?

We are using nuget to manage packages, and he has tried force reinstalling the latest version of json.net with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what might fix this?